# Caminho relativo em Java

Tags: java, sistema-de-arquivos, caminho-relativo

Eu preciso ler um txt. Só que meu projeto tem que ser extensível. tipo q não funcione só na minha maquina. Acho que o arquivo txt teria que ficar na pasta do projeto, e colocar um caminha relativo. mas não sei fazer isso. me ajudem.

Atualmente partes do código estão assim:

```
ManipuladorArquivo manipuladorArquivo = new ManipuladorArquivo("C:\\Users\\Vinicius\\Downloads\\politicos.txt");
```

---

```
public class ManipuladorArquivo {

   private String caminhoArquivo;

   public ManipuladorArquivo(String caminhoArquivo) {
       this.caminhoArquivo = caminhoArquivo;
   }
}
```

Comment: String caminhoDoArquivo = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
caminhoDoArquivo.concat("politicos.txt");
Isto resulta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer que o arquivo esteja no projeto, basta entrar na pasta do seu projeto e colar o arquivo lá dentro.
então como falado na resposta anterior, você passa o caminho relativo ao local do arquivo que esta chamando ele.

se o seu aquivo esta na raiz do projeto e seu arquivo também, basta chamar ele direto;

```
String caminho = "arquivo.txt";
```

caminho relativo:

**Arquivos no mesmo local:**

```
 String caminho = "arquivo.txt";
```

**Arquivo em uma pasta anterior, volta e chama o arquivo:**

```
String caminho = "../arquivo.txt";
```

**Arquivo em uma pasta a frente, chama a pasta e o arquivo:**

```
String caminho = "pasta/arquivo.txt";
```

lembrando que é sempre partindo do local onde esta o seu script que vai chamar o arquivo.txt;

agora caso queira chamar de outro lugar do computador, você tem diversas opções, mas uma delas é usar as variáveis do windows.

exemplo: `"C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Downloads\\politicos.txt";`

Answer (score 1):

Os caminhos no Java são relativos aonde o  seu .jar esta localizado, você que está passando um caminho absoluto na sua variável.

Os caminhos relativos também vão ser diferentes nas IDEs enquanto você programa.

Por exemplo, utilizando o Intellij, a IDE irá criar uma hierarquia semelhante a essa.

```
projeto/
  src/
    Main.java
  photos/ 
    icone.png
```

Se eu quiser acessar icone.png usando caminhos relativos:

```
String path = "photos/icone.png";
```

Se eu quiser acessar icone.png usando caminhos absolutos:

```
String path = "C:/Users/Alguem/projeto/photos/icone.png";
```

Comment: Eu uso o Netbeans, mas eu não achei onde fica esse .jar para passar o caminho a partir dele.